# Retrieve item from the middle of a PriorityQueue in Java

Tags: java, priority-queue

Given the following code:

```
import java.util.*;

class SimpleTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>();

        pq.add(1);
        pq.add(2);
        pq.add(3);
        pq.add(4);
        pq.add(5);
        pq.add(6);
        pq.add(7);

        int index = 0;
        int middleNumber = 0;
        Iterator it = pq.iterator();

        //Is number odd
        if(pq.size() % 2 != 0) {
            System.out.println(pq.size());

            //keep removing from queue until we reached queueSize/2 (rounded up)
            while(it.hasNext() && index++ <= ((pq.size() >> 1) + 1)) {
                middleNumber = pq.poll();
            }
            System.out.println("The middle number is: " + (float)middleNumber);
        }       

    }
}
```

This works on some odd numbers, but not others, and I fail to see why.

Given a queue of 7 items, the code above returns 4 which is in the middle of the queue.

But If I try a queue with 9 elements (1-9). It also returns 4, when it should be 5.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Can you explain what your logic does?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I updated with some comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that this line:

```
                middleNumber = pq.poll();
```

decrements the size of the queue, which affects the meaning of this line:

```
            while(it.hasNext() && index++ <= ((pq.size() >> 1) + 1)) {
```

Then there are secondary problems — the `while` expression is wrong as written — which I think is because you tried to tweak the `while` to work for the case where the queue started with 7 elements, not understanding the underlying bug.

Instead, you should precompute what index you want, and poll to that point:

```
int indexOfMiddleNumber = pq.size() / 2;
for (int index = 0; index < indexOfMiddleNumber; ++index) {
    pq.poll();
}
int middleNumber = pq.poll();
```

(Note that there's no use for the iterator, and it's actually a really bad idea to call `it.hasNext()` in a loop that's also modifying the underlying collection. I'm surprised that `PriorityQueue` isn't giving you a `ConcurrentModificationException` for this.)

Answer (score -1):

The iterator of a `PriorityQueue` doesn't iterate in priority order, just in the natural order of the underlying collection. See the Javadoc.

The only way to get the priority order is by calling `PriorityQueue.remove().`

Comment: -1, sorry. Everything you're saying about `PriorityQueue` is correct, but the OP *is* removing elements; the iterator is just used for its `hasNext()`. (Which, I mean, is still quite wrong. But your answer doesn't address it.)